# Properly using dataclasses to return values of items

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses

The project is to sort items - using a particular algorithm - into boxes. I am having trouble after assigning each items to the proper class, to return to another function and use and modify the data held within the object in the data class.

My testing file looks like this:

```
17 10 4
Abacus 3
Blender 5
Chessboard 3
Dishes 6
```

My classes:

```
@dataclass
class InventoryItem:
    name: str
    weight: float


@dataclass
class BoxInventory:
    name: str
    maxWeight: float
    remainingWeight: float
    contents: dict = ""
    """
    def listContents(self, contents):
        self.listContents = contents

    def remainingWeight(self, remainingWeight):
        self.remainingWeight = remainingWeight

    def addItemWeight(self, itemWeight):
        self.remainingWeight -= itemWeight

    def addItemList(self, itemName, itemWeight, contents):
        self.contents = contents[itemName] = contents[itemWeight]
    """
```

Here is where I read my text file and transfer it to a class:

```
"""
Take the given txt file and format into proper list for boxes and items
:param filename: The filename of the text file
:return: Send lists to to be used by an algo.
"""
with open(filename, 'r') as myFile:  # Open the correct file
    itemDict = {}
    boxDict = {}

    myList = [line.split() for line in myFile.readlines()]
    boxLine = ' '.join(myList[0])

    for line in range(1, len(myList)):
        lines = ''.join(myList[line])
        itemName = lines[:-1]
        weight = lines[len(lines) - 1:]

        item = InventoryItem(itemName, int(weight))
        itemDict[itemName] = [item]

    boxString = ""
    count = 0
    for char in boxLine:
        if char != " ":
            boxString = boxString + char
        else:
            boxName = "Box" + str(count)
            box = BoxInventory(boxName, int(boxString), int(boxString))
            boxDict[boxName] = [box]
            boxString = ""
            count += 1

myReturn = {}
myReturn['boxDict'] = boxDict
myReturn['itemDict'] = itemDict
return myReturn
```

Non-implemented algorithm:

```
def roomiest(myReturnDict):
    """
    For each item find the box with the greatest remaining allowed weight that can support the item and place the item in that box
    :param boxList: The list of boxes in the class from the given file
    :param itemList: The list of items in the class from the given file
    :return: If boxes were able to fit all items(1); items in box with individual weights(2); Box name with max
    weight(3); items with their weights that were left behind(4)
    """
    itemList = myReturnDict.get("itemDict")
    boxList = myReturnDict.get("boxDict")
```

> My problem is that I do know how to read the parsed data from my
>   fileReader function in my algo. function.

Answer (score 0):

Your input function is a little strange as you're storing the objects in a list of length 1 inside a dictionary. So your data looks like:

```
'Dishes': [InventoryItem(name='Dishes', weight=6)]
```

instead of

```
'Dishes': InventoryItem(name='Dishes', weight=6)
```

You might have a reason for it, but changing `itemDict[itemName] = [item]` to `itemDict[itemName] = item` makes your code a little easier to follow (and the same for `boxDict[boxName] = [box]`). With that change you can access the parsed data easily with the following:

```
for item_name, item in itemList.items():
    print(item.name)
    print(item.weight)
```

This iterates through the itemList dictionary, getting the key, value pairs which in this case is itemName, item (or [item] in your original code. If you don't want to change that, replace item with item[0] in the code above). Then you can access attributes of your Class directly by calling their label.

You can get the box with most space remaining, using

```
sorted_box_list = (sorted(boxList.values(), key=operator.attrgetter('remainingWeight'), reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is rather than using a dictionay I am using a list to pass on the data to a new function.

Text File --> List --> Dict --> List --> sortedList

Here is my new fileReader function:

```
def fileReader(filename):
    """
    Take the given txt file and format into proper list for boxes and items
    :param filename: The filename of the text file
    :return: Send lists to to be used by an algo.
    """
    with open(filename, 'r') as myFile:  # Open the correct file
        itemList = []
        boxList = []

        myList = [line.split() for line in myFile.readlines()]
        boxLine = ' '.join(myList[0])

        for line in range(1, len(myList)):
            lines = ''.join(myList[line])
            itemName = lines[:-1]
            weight = lines[len(lines) - 1:]

            item = InventoryItem(itemName, int(weight))
            itemList.append(item)

        boxString = ""
        count = 0
        for char in boxLine:
            if char != " ":
                boxString = boxString + char
            else:
                boxName = "Box" + str(count)
                box = BoxInventory(boxName, int(boxString), int(boxString))
                boxList.append(box)
                boxString = ""
                count += 1
```

I then read and sort the data in each algotithm using this same method:

```
def roomiest(myReturnDict):
    """
    For each item find the box with the greatest remaining allowed weight that can support the item and place the item in that box
    :param boxList: The list of boxes in the class from the given file
    :param itemList: The list of items in the class from the given file
    :return: If boxes were able to fit all items(1); items in box with individual weights(2); Box name with max
    weight(3); items with their weights that were left behind(4)
    """
    itemData = list(myReturnDict.get("itemList"))
    boxData = list(myReturnDict.get("boxList"))

    sortedItemList = sorted(itemData, key=lambda x: x.weight, reverse=True)
    sortedBoxList = sorted(boxData, key=lambda x: x.remainingWeight, reverse=True)
        myReturn = {}

        myReturn['boxList'] = boxList
        myReturn['itemList'] = itemList
        return myReturn
```

My dataclasses look like the following:

```
@dataclass
class InventoryItem:
    name: str
    weight: float


@dataclass
class BoxInventory:
    name: str
    maxWeight: float
    remainingWeight: float
    contents: dict = ""


def itemWeight(item):
    print("Weight of", item.name, "is: ", item.weight, "\n")
    return item.weight


def remainWeight(box):
    print("Rem. weight in ", box.name, "is: ", box.remainingWeight, "\n")
    return box.remainingWeight
```

Comment: You declair InventoryItem weight as float but fill it all the time with int!